# How does jars in my local .m2 repo picked up by my websphere server?

Tags: java, maven, websphere

I am new to Maven, I have bunch of jar files in my pom file which are installed in my local .m2 repo. I am able to clean install my project and build successfully. But when i deploy my EAR project on to websphere server it is throwing class not found exception with many jars (like spring framework jars). How to resolve this issue?

I also have a question on how server picks up jars in .m2 repo?? Please make me understand

Comment: Can you provide the pom.xml (package conf & spring dependency definition) ?

Comment: <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
  <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>

<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: packaging is defined here as 'war', so you can't have an EAR at the end (except if you built it manually somewhere outside maven or do not copy here the shade/assembly conf or your pom).

Comment: I am sorry we have other maven project where we use this war to build an ear. Later, ear is deployed on server

Answer (score 1):

Some things to be noted here:

1. Make sure the pom scope of that jar is not `provided` if so change it to `compile` or move the jars manually to the websphere configured jar lookup `lib` folder
2. If this is a simple java application of some purpose(not webapp) use `Maven Shade` plugin (Usually `webapps` builds along with the required jars in the lib directory).

Comment: 1. I didn't specify the scope. So by default it should be compile. 
 2. It is a web project. I need war file out of it. I searched my webapps folder there is no lib directory out there

Comment: unzip your `WAR` file and check the needed jars are present in it.

Comment: Yes i am able to see the jar file  in war. But still  server is throwing below error during run time. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.access.WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator

Comment: can you check the logs of your war file installation & startup and see any errors there?